# how to convert 3 bytes in little endian order to a floating number from -1 to +1

Tags: numbers, lazarus, floating, 24-bit

I have 3 bytes in little-endian.
these are: Top, Middle and Bottom (from bit 23 to bit 0)
How can I convert them to a float number from -1 to +1?

3 bytes are in little-endian because there is the string RIFF In the wav
so min value is (0x7FFFFF) and the max value is (0x800000)

http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/audio/javaWavFiles.html

for a 16 bit wav: the wave frames are in 2s complementary binary between -32768; 0x8000 and 32767; 0x7FFF)

Comment: This is not a standard format. You need to know how the floating point value is encoded. Only you can determine that.

Comment: 3 byte of data from a wav 24 bit.
http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/audio/javaWavFiles.html
these 3 bytes are in little - endian .. there is RIFF In the descriptor

Comment: Please provide this information in the question

Comment: That link doesn't quite make sense to me. I don't understand where the ranges come from, they don't tally with my understand of what 24 bit two's complement arithmetic implies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you provide looks wrong to me. Surely the 24 bit format uses standard [two's complement arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). In which case `0x7FFFFF` represents `-8388608` and `0x800000` represents `8388607`.

On that basis you use this function to convert your three bytes into a signed integer value:

```
function TwosComplement24(const Bytes): Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  Move(Bytes, Result, 3);
  Result := (Result and $7fffff) - (Result and $800000);
end;
```

Once you have that in place, you can convert to a floating point value like this:

```
function Sample24toReal(const Bytes): Double;
begin
  Result := TwosComplement24(Bytes) / 8388608;
end;
```

I've used an untyped parameter for the 3 bytes, but you may want to do it differently depending on how you read the data.

Also, this code is written assuming that it runs on a little endian machine. If the data is little endian, and the machine is big endian, then you would need to reverse each group of three bytes.

Comment: ok these works. and to get back 3 bytes after a manipulation of the float?

Comment: Do the reverse operations

Comment: function MyToByteL(fl : extended):longint;
var ret1 : longint;
var retval2 : extended;
begin
  ret1 := 0;
  ret1 := 0;
  retval2 := fl;

  retval2 := round(retval2 * 8388608);
  ret1 := round(retval2);


  ret1 := (ret1 and $7fffff) -(ret1 and $800000);

  result := ret1;

end;   

it does not work

Comment: No, the conversion between 32 bit two's complement and 24 bit two's complement is wrong. We can't do this in comments. Would need to be a new question. I do think I have answered this question and that you are in a position to accept the answer.

Comment: i can't open another question. how can i do?

Comment: Probably you have to wait to ask again. What does SO tell you? It's going to be something like an or with $800000 if the value is negative and then that Move with the args reversed.

Comment: can you make a screeshot?

Comment: with iteration is it too long can you help  me?

Comment: You just need to shift the sign bit down, like this: `if Value and $80000000 <> 0 then
  Value := Value or $00800000;
Move(Value, Bytes, 3);`